# Multi-Feature One-Hot-Encoder with varying amount of feature instances

Tags: python, scikit-learn, encoding, preprocessor, one-hot-encoding

Let's assume we have data instances like this:

```
[
    [15, 20, ("banana","apple","cucumber"), ...],
    [91, 12, ("orange","banana"), ...],
    ...
]
```

I am wondering how I can encode the third element of these datapoints. For multiple features values we could use sklearn's [OneHotEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html), but as far as I could find out, it cannot handle inputs of different length.

Here is what I've tried out:

```
X = [[15, 20, ("banana","apple","cucumber")], [91, 12, ("orange","banana")]]

ct = ColumnTransformer(
    [
        ("genre_encoder", OneHotEncoder(), [2])
    ],
    remainder='passthrough'
)
print(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

This will only output

```
[[1.0 0.0 15 20]
 [0.0 1.0 91 12]]
```

as expected, because the tuples are handled as the possible values this feature can be represented with.

We can't embed our features directly (like `[15, 12, "banana", "apple", "cucumber"]`), because

1. we don't know how many instances of this feature we will have (two? three?)
2. each position would be interpreted as an own feature and thus if we had `banana` in the first nominal slot in one datapoint and in the second one in our second nominal slot, they would not count to the same "pool of values" a feature can embody

Example:

```
X = [["banana","apple","cucumber"], ["orange","banana", "cucumber"]]
enc = OneHotEncoder()
print(enc.fit_transform(X).toarray())

[[1. 0. 1. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 1. 1.]]
```

This representation contains 5 slots instead of 4, because the first slot is interpreted as using `banana` or `orange`, the second one as `apple` or `banana` and the last one only has the option `cucumber`.

(This would also not solve the problem of having different amounts of feature values per datapoint. And replacing empty ones with `None` does not solve the problem either, because then `None` faces this positional ambiguity.)

Any idea how to encode those "Multi-Muliti-"features, that can take multiple values and consist of a varying amount of elements? Thank you in advance!

Comment: [MultiLabelBinarizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer.html) seems to do more of what I want to achieve, but the documentation and the class name itself tells us to use it for classes. So, is there another good way for features?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it for now by transforming it into a CountVectorizer Problem, thanks to David Maspis answer [on the datascience stackexchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/88666/111048).